# How to make numeric keyboard appear on entry of view controller in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

I would like to make the numeric keyboard appear on entry of a view controller. What would I need to add to the back end to do that, and would I put it in the ViewDidLoad()?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call BecomeFirstResponder on any UITextField (or other keyboard control) in your View

```
myUITextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

Comment: Hey @Jason. This worked great. What would I need to do if I wanted to have the keyboard appear on another viewcontroller in the same class? Thanks, Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **KeyboardType** of your **UITextField** and call **BecomeFirstResponder** to display the keyboard.

```
yourUITextField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
yourUITextField.BecomeFirstResponder();
```